# NestJS installation npm WARN deprecated

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

When I try to install NestJS via
`npm i -g @nestjs/cli`, I get:

```
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
```

Is this expected behavior to install Nest? Or is something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after try it at all, uninstalling node, trying to remove that `sourcemap-codec` package, everything.

```bash
sudo npm i -g @nestjs/cli
```